# Calculate price including and excluding VAT both ways keeping the same outcome

Tags: javascript, formula

We calculate VAT and round to 2 decimals. Only the value excuding VAT is stored. When reloading the page, we calculate what the price including VAT is.

```js
let includingVat = 4000;
let excludingVat = +(includingVat / 121 * 100).toFixed(2);

console.log(+(excludingVat / 100 * 121).toFixed(2));
```

As you can see, the calculated value now has an added 'cent'. How do we avoid this?

Comment: Use `.toFixed(0)` instead of 2.

Comment: Always calculate in cents, not euros, that way you don't get the rounding error. To display in euro, divide by 100.

Answer (score 2):

`toFixed()` is not a rounding function, but it is a number formatting function that returns a string. So use `toFixed()` only for visualization:

```
let includingVat = 4000;
let excludingVat = includingVat / 121 * 100;
//                ^ + removed              ^^^ toFixed() removed
console.log( (excludingVat / 100 * 121).toFixed(2) );
//          ^ + removed
```

And the output is: `4000.00`.

Anyway, using cent instead of euro is generally the better way. (see other answers).

Answer (score 1):

Always store prices in cents, this will avoid rounding errors on various calculations.

If you receive the price in euros then multiply by 100 and store that

```js
let receivedPriceInEuro = 4000;

let item = 
{
   price: receivedPriceInEuro*100,
   get excludingVAT()
   { 
     return this.price / 12100 * 10000;
   },
   get displayPrice()
   {
     return (this.price/100).toFixed(2);
   },
   get displayPriceExVAT()
   {
     return (this.excludingVAT/100).toFixed(2);
   }
};

console.log(`Price: €${item.displayPrice}, excluding VAT: €${item.displayPriceExVAT}`);
```